# Al usar useSelector retorna null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Estoy utilizando redux para manejar el estado de mi aplicacion.
Tengo la siguiente tabla que hacer click en el boton de info actualiza el valor de **tramiteEnVista** en mi estado.
[image: Esta es la tabla de registros]

Cuando hago click en el boton info ejecuta lo siguiente:

```
const handleInfoButtonClick = (e, id) =>{
        dispatch(startSetTramiteEnVista(id));
    }
```

Ejecuta la siguiente accion

```
export const startSetTramiteEnVista = (idTramite) => {
    return async(dispatch)=>{
        try {
            const resp = await tokenFetch(`tramites/${idTramite}`);
            const {tramite} = await resp.json();
            dispatch(setTramiteEnVista(tramite))
        } catch (error) {
            Swal.fire('Error', 'Error al traer tramite por id', 'error');
        }
    }
}
const setTramiteEnVista = (tramite)=>({
    type: types.setTramiteEnVista,
    payload: tramite
})
```

Y el estado queda así:
[image: Estado de redux]

**EL PROBLEMA SURGE AL MOMENTO DE EXTRAER EL VALOR DE tramiteEnVista con useDispatch**
En el componente VerTramite intento extraer la informacion de tramiteEnVista pero me retorna null

```
export const VerTramite = () => {


    const tramite= useSelector(state=>state.tramites.tramiteEnVista);
    console.log('Tramite en VerTramite: ', tramite);
    const numIngreso = tramite.numIngreso;
    return (   

        //TODO: cargar el tramite por id al estado
        <Container>
             <div className="breadcrumb">
                    <Breadcrumb
                        routeSegments={[
                            { name: 'Mis Tramites', path: '/tramites/my' },
                            { name: `ver` },
                        ]}
                    />
                </div>
                
                <SimpleCard title={`Trámite N°: ${numIngreso}`}>
                   <VerTramiteCard/>
                </SimpleCard>
        </Container>
      )
}
```

Pero obtengo esto:
[image: Error en ver tramites]

Y en la consola:
[image: Error en consola]

No entiendo por que me retorna null porque si existe el valor en el estado.

Comment: as intentando hace un console.log(tramite)  e antes de asignar tramite.numIngreso

Comment: No sé exactamente el proceso que hay al hacer click en info, pero una posibilidad puede ser que cuando esté renderizando ese componente, aún no exista en la store por eso te devuelva null. Prueba `const numIngreso = tramite?.numIngreso` así numIngreso será null al principio, pero cuando haya datos en la store tendrá el valor que debería. luego pondría un renderizado condicional si numIngreso no tiene valor retorna <></> y si lo tiene retorna lo que estás retornando ahora

Comment: Es por eso: no existe aún la información en el store. Lo solucioné tal y como lo dices. Gracias